# Как изменить размер ImageView?

Tags: java, android, button, imageview

На фрагменте есть несколько ImageView и Button.
При клике на Button, требуется изменить размеры ImageView(т.е. самого компонента).
Вся разметка в RelativeLayout.

Пытаюсь добиться результата следующим способом:

```
int width = myImageView.getWidth() + 100;
int height = myImageView.getHeight() + 100;
myImageView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height));
```

При клике на Button, успешно происходит увеличение размеров ImageView.
При повторных кликах - результатов нет, т.е. размеры ImageView больше не меняются.
В какую сторону смотреть?

Comment: Кажется, вы опечатались и у вас размеры должны браться и назначаться одному виджету, а не двум

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо за замечание. Перемудрил с упрощением кода для примера. Размеры берутся из нужного виджета

Comment: попробуйте вызвать myImageView.invalidate()  в самом конце

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) myImageView.getLayoutParams();
params.width += 100;
params.height += 100;
myImageView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: ваш ответ полностью отвечает на мой вопрос. Подскажите, что было в моем коде не так? Визуально они практически одинаковы, на мой взгляд.

Comment: @АлександрТкаченко, на самом деле я точно не знаю, но, думаю, это как-то связано с тем, что вы в вашем коде назначали новые параметры вьюхе, а не изменяли текущие. Плюс, не всегда `getWidth/Height` работают так, как можно было бы ожидать. Т.е. лучше их вообще не использовать, а брать размеры из параметров